# Images are again loaded while scrolling the Listview in android

Tags: android

My images are again getting loaded when I scroll my listview.

Here is my getview method of my adapter.

```
 @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
//      if(itemView==null){
//      final int x=position;
         Log.e("view Touched..","dsfgvdvgd");
         LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
//       LayoutInflater inflator = getLayoutInflater();
         itemView=inflator.inflate(resId, null);
//      }
         // name
        TextView name=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        name.setText(usersSS.get(position).getUsername());


        TextView state=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        state.setText(usersSS.get(position).getState());



        //image
        ImageView img = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userimage);
        if(position==3){
        Log.e("image urls",usersSS.get(position).getUserthumb());
        }
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(usersSS.get(position).getUserthumb().replace(" ","%20"), img);

        // rating stars..

        int[] stars = {R.id.star1,R.id.star2,R.id.star3,R.id.star4,R.id.star5};
        if(!usersSS.get(position).getRating().equals(""))
        {
            int i=Integer.parseInt(usersSS.get(position).getRating());
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++)
            {
                ImageView imgv =(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(stars[j]);
                imgv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.star_on);
            }
        }


         Log.e("view","view");
        return itemView;

    }
```

I tried with keeping, if(convertView==null){} but then,wrong images are loaded first and after scrolling correct images are loaded.

Please help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Check out this qustion, it's got all the answers you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: can you please refer my code to solve this

Comment: I posted a solution below, did it help?

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries like picasso https://github.com/square/picasso or Universal Image Loader or Volley for image loading. It would be way too easy if you use these libraries.

I am adding example code snippet you can use with picasso.

First of all I would say, Please use view reuse pattern in your getView, along with viewholder.

```
private static final int IMAGE_HEIGHT = 100;
private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 100;
public static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView title;
    public TextView subTitle;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return usersSS.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(null == convertView) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_user_data, parent, false);  
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        holder.subTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.state);          
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    User user = (User) getItem(position);
    holder.title.setText(user.getUserName());
    holder.subTitle.setText(user.getState);
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getUserThumb())) {
        Picasso.with(context).load(user.getUserThumb)
                .error(R.drawable.dummy_image)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.dummyImage)
                .resize(IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH).centerCrop()

                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```